# MySQL and PHP file retrieve

Tags: php, mysql

It is a simple upload form , all the info and files are getting uploaded in the db ,
but when i am trying to retrieve , the file name is coming but when i call for the actual file, it is giving -

> File Uploaded Successfully.%PDF-1.5\r\n%µµµµ\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<>>>\r\nendobj\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<>\r\nendobj\r\n3 0 obj\r\n<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>\r\nendobj\r\n4 0 obj\r\n<>\r\nstream\r\nxœuŽ1Â0…÷@þÃë’Ü¥d(š¦R± ˜Mœüÿ«—Aˆïàà=îñ=Ø†ÁniAãˆiN˜ŠVvapDyjÅ YFp†œG g¢CykExÕsÔ\ndˆÅ|Ü:ìçº½úµDßQNZeWø—è|0Ü·D±+£äkÁ²žóŸ`ÏÞDnƒÒ«ùEÞ>,«-Ž\r\nendstream\r\nendobj\r\n5 0 obj\r\n<>\r\nendobj\r\n6 0 ob

the whole output is filled with this code...

---

PHP Code is

```
if(isset ($_POST["submit"]))
  {

      mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysqli_select_db("upload");

      $fileName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

      $fileData = mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));

      $fileType = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES["file"]["type"]);

      if($fileType== "application/pdf" || $fileType == "application/word")
      {
          mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `files` VALUES('','$fileName','$fileData')");
          echo "File Uploaded Successfully.";
         }

      else
      {
          echo "This type of file is not allowed.";
      }


      $result = mysqli_query("SELECT `Name` , `File` FROM `files`" );

      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo $fileData; 


      echo "<br />";

      echo $fileName;



  }
```

Any help please !!

Comment: Well, what exactly did you expect `echo $fileData` to do?

Comment: You've uploaded the file and then promptly echoed it back to the browser. You _haven't_ set up the appropriate headers so the the browser thinks it's supposed to treat it as HTML and displays it. It's not clear what you actually intend to do here.

Comment: That's obviously a PDF file. So if you want to view it, you would either add a header, or link to it directly with an `href`. which in turn should open up Adobe Acrobat Reader should that be the associated program on your computer. You can't just echo it like that.

Comment: so what would be the code like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the mime-type (example:application/pdf) of the file along with full file name (example: test.pdf) and then, after selecting the row from the database and retrieving the 3 columns (mimetype,filename,filecontent), you can do something like :

```
<?php
/*
Assuming $row contains the returned values from the database and
that it has values in these 3 columns : mimetype, filename, filecontent
*/
header('Content-Type: '.$row['mimetype']);
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$row['filename'].'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($row['filecontent']));
echo $row['filecontent'];
?>
```